# Azure DevOps board query

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps board queries if I select "Work Item Type" = "Task" then on the results it is showing Epic, Feature, User Stories, and Task. My requirement is I need to select only the tasks but it is not showing that

Comment: can you please share a screenshot of your query?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I use an Operator of `In` as opposed to `=`, and this seems to work correctly (I have to use a second query parameter to get my result list below 20,000 hits but this should illustrate how I did it:

[image: Example query]